# Loop through list based on number of characters of user input

Tags: python, list, loops, python-itertools

I am using a list to hold strings.  A user inputs a message and each character is searched for in the list.

```
for count, letter in enumerate(newMessage):
    foundAt = myList[count].find(letter)
```

I'm using the count variable to access the proper element in the list but when there are more characters than elements in the list it returns an error. If I had ten elements on the eleventh character I would want it to search the first element.

Comment: When you say "If I had ten elements on the eleventh character I would want it to search the first element." do you mean you want it to search in `mylist[0]` for the eleventh character?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you just want to circle around the list as you go through it? (So if the list is 10 elements, 0-9 corresponds to 10-19, 20-29, etc.)

You could do:

```
for count, letter in enumerate(newMessage):
    foundAt = myList[count % len(myList)].find(letter)
```